# Jquery not console.log variable in firefox console

Tags: html, jquery

I try to get the data value form the text input, console not log it...
Just after I use breakpoint but without it's not console anything
What's the problem?

```js
var x = ''
$(() => {
  $("#enter").click(() => {

    x = $('#dataText').val();
    console.log(x);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
  <div>
    <h1> welcome to performance parser</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form>
      <div class="mb-5 p-4">
        <label for="enterFolderName" class="form-label">Folder name</label>
        <input id="dataText" type="text" class="form-control" id="enterFolderName">
        <button id="enter" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. It's probably removed when the page reloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form submits, the page reloads (no action).

To see the value EITHER check the "Preserve log" or use preventDefault:

```js
var x = ''
$(() => {
  $("#enter").click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submit

    x = $('#dataText').val();
    console.log(x);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
    <div>
      <h1> welcome to performance parser</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form>
        <div class="mb-5 p-4">
          <label for="enterFolderName" class="form-label">Folder name</label>
          <input id="dataText" type="text" class="form-control" id="enterFolderName">
          <button id="enter" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

I would personally use

```
 $("form").on("submit",e => {
```